# Redirect of to wrong url behind reverse proxy if trailing slash of folder is omitted

Tags: nginx

I have this simple NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stdout;

    root /webroot;
    index index.html;
}
```

My NGINX server is behind a reverse proxy.

When I access a folder containing a index.html via for example

```
http://proxy_hostname/folder/
```

everything works fine.

When I access a folder containing a index.html without the trailing slash, NGINX trys to redirect to a url with the trailing slash. Which is fine, but the target host is wrong.

http://proxy_hostname/folder is redirected to http://hostname/folder/

This also occures in my dev environment, where the server is accessed via an forwarded port (8070 to 80):

http://127.0.0.1:8070/folder is redirected to http://127.0.0.1/folder/

How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: There are three directives that control what name and port is used in the redirect. You may need to change [`absolute_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#absolute_redirect) to off.

Comment: absolure_redirect is someting I tryed but this failes if the reverse proxy adds an directory to the url (which will be omitted in the redirect).

Comment: If the reverse proxy is adding a directory, maybe you need to fix the problem there. For example (if it was also Nginx), adding one or more [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) rules to maintain the reverse proxy mappings.